# testing using unity and accessor classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, testing, mvvm, unity-container

So I need to test some view models that have a private field containing an adapter, this adapter gets manipulated via ICommands / input / etc from the views, I think this is a pretty common model, the view exposes some public properties that are specific to what that particular view is all about and then then the adapter is concelled in a private field. Now my problem is testing. I am using Unity to register an instance of that adapter and then each view model gets that same instance of course but I can't test it cause it is private so I created an accessor class but I can't figure out how to create and instance of it. Maybe some code will help explain what I am trying to do. Now keep in mind I am new to testing so if I am totally confused about something please let me know.

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
  container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<IEventAggregator, EventAggregator>();
  container.RegisterType<IRegionManager, RegionManager>();
  //Notice that I am not calling registertype but later on I call container.Resolve asking for 
  //CreateRgaViewModel - this is because I don't have to regiter the types / instances of 
  //whatever I am directly asking for but I do have to register anything it depends on. 
  //container.RegisterType<CreateRgaViewModel>();
  var adapter = new RgaWizardAdapter(container);
  //So we don't want to get any data at this point because this is not an integrration test
  //adapter.InitializeRga(873632);

  container.RegisterInstance<IRgaWizardAdapter>("RgaAdapterInstance", adapter);

  var appCommands = new ApplicationCommands(container);
  container.RegisterInstance<IApplicationCommands>(appCommands);
}

[TestMethod]
public void CanCreate_CreateRgaViewModelAndGetNamedInstanceOfRgaDocument()
{
  try
  {
    //this fails 
    //CreateRgaViewModel_Accessor createRgaViewModel = container.Resolve<CreateRgaViewModel_Accessor>();
    //this works
    CreateRgaViewModel createRgaViewModel = container.Resolve<CreateRgaViewModel>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(createRgaViewModel, "CreateRgaViewModel was null");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }
}
```

My problem is that I find a lot of stuff on testing but it seems to be specific to using silverlight. I am not creating a silverlight app, this is desktop WPF / MVVM app.

Thanks for your help